# Encapsulamento de código OpenGL em classes C++

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

Estou atualmente iniciando um projeto baseado em SDL / OpenGL, usando como base o código [desse artigo](https://open.gl/content/code/c5_reflection.txt). No momento, estou tentando encontrar a melhor forma de encapsular o código OpenGL do exemplo. Minha função main é a seguinte:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL", 100, 100, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    //glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    SDL_Event windowEvent;
    while (1)
    {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
        {
            if (windowEvent.type == SDL_QUIT) break;
            if (windowEvent.type == SDL_KEYUP && windowEvent.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) break;
        }

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Nesse código, minha intenção é instanciar os objetos OpenGL que irão representar os elementos da minha cena. Pretendo implementar os seguintes tipos:

1- terreno
2- céu (imagem JPEG panorâmica)
3- construções (baseado em projetos do Autocad)
4- veículos (também baseado em projetos Autocad)
5- personagens (projetos Blender)

cada elemento é implementado por objetos que são todos derivados de um classe comum (sendo implementada), que irá ter alguns métodos comuns que retornarão array de vértices e outros elementos necessários para o código OpenGL.

É nessa classe que queria implementar método(s) para criar/compilar/usar os shaders necessários para que a placa de vídeo renderize o objeto 3D. Minha dúvida é como implementar isso: ponho todo o código no construtor/destrutor ou é melhor dividir em vários métodos (nesse caso, qual a melhor forma de distribuir esse código)?

Além disso, com essas classes prontas, qual a melhor forma de integrar os objetos instanciados dessas classes no código acima? Minha ideia inicial (que não sei se é correta ou a melhor), é instanciar o objeto fora do loop de eventos, dentro dele chamar um método como "display(...)" da classe, e fora dele, antes da exclusão do contexto, chamar um outro método da classe (como um "destroy(...)").

Alguém tem alguma sugestão sobre esse tópico?

Comment: Hum... de certa forma o que você quer fazer é construir a sua própria engine de renderização 3D. Nada de errado, e nada contra. Mas há algum motivo pra isso (talvez estudar OpenGL)? Por que, do ponto de vista de produtividade, seria melhor usar algo já pronto, como alguma biblioteca gráfica mais geral como a [Allegro](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=3D_using_OpenGL) ou mesmo uma engine 3D como a [Unity](https://unity3d.com/pt).

Comment: @LuizVieira Muito mais do que aprender sobre OpenGL, meu objetivo é criar algo otimizado para os formatos de arquivos que eu pretendo utilizar (além dos que eu mencionei no tópico). Em um outro forum, alguém me sugeriu criar classes para cadas shader e outros itens similares, e usar essas classes nas classes que representam meus elementos da cena 3D. Você teria alguma sugestão de quais tipos de shader são usados para cada tipo de elemento listado acima?

Comment: Entendi Kleber. Bom, eu não vou dar uma resposta porque eu já não mexo diretamente no OpenGL há alguns bons anos. Mas encapsular os objetos em classes é uma boa ideia. A interface padrão deles pode facilitar não somente o acesso aos Shaders como também centralizar outras questões importantes (de uma biblioteca de física, por exemplo, incluindo definições necessárias como massa, dimensão, etc). A minha sugestão é explorar bem os conceitos da OO, e até mesmo procurar alguns padrões de design interessantes.

Comment: Talvez o [Bridge](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software)) seja útil pra separar a construção geral (os vértices) do objeto do shader utilizado (como os vértices vão ser de fato renderizados). Boa sorte! :)